# Thread support in scheme scm 5e5 implementation

Tags: scheme

I have been learning Scheme for a few months now using scm 5e5 under Debian 8 and going through SICP. I am also going through Concept, Techniques, and Models of Computer Programming and I feel confident enough to emulate the code examples in Scheme now rather than adopt the Mozart system. In general, I find it a pleasure to learn computing attempting to replicate a language construct of say C++/Java/C#, Python or Haskell in Scheme or vice-versa. However, I am now having trouble dealing with concurrency constructs as I cannot find how to obtain thread support with scm. I have been able to use fork and execl but that's not quite the same. I have looked at the doc (scm manual and slib manual but can't see anything related to thread support). I couldn't see anything in the MIT-scheme documentation. I have just installed guile and it looks that guile will do it. However, I love my scm. Do I have to give it up in order to play with threads? Or is there something I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, grepping through the SCM documentation and sources, it looks like there is no Scheme-level threading library available for SCM.

You get to use Guile. :-P (Disclosure: I'm a Guile committer.)

Comment: Thanks very much Chris.